# How can I access the Cognito username of the caller in a Lamda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have added authorization to the API endpoint in the API Gateway.

This added the `identity` property, which seems relevant, to event.

```
identity: 
{ 
    cognitoIdentityPoolId: null,
    accountId: null,
    cognitoIdentityId: null,
    caller: null,
    sourceIp: 'detracted',
    accessKey: null,
    cognitoAuthenticationType: null,
    cognitoAuthenticationProvider: null,
    userArn: null,
    userAgent: 'Amazon CloudFront',
    user: null },
    apiId: 'detracted' },
    body: null,
    isBase64Encoded: false 
}
```

But there is mostly `null` there. So how can I access the Cognito username of the caller?

EDIT:

I added a mapping template. It is a GET request however, so I don't know if it has any effect, as the tooltip explains that the data is attached to the body.

```
##  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html
##  This template will pass through all parameters including path, querystring, header, stage variables, and context through to the integration endpoint via the body/payload
#set($allParams = $input.params())
{
"body-json" : $input.json('$'),
"params" : {
#foreach($type in $allParams.keySet())
    #set($params = $allParams.get($type))
"$type" : {
    #foreach($paramName in $params.keySet())
    "$paramName" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($params.get($paramName))"
        #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
}
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
},
"stage-variables" : {
#foreach($key in $stageVariables.keySet())
"$key" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($stageVariables.get($key))"
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
},
"context" : {
    "account-id" : "$context.identity.accountId",
    "api-id" : "$context.apiId",
    "api-key" : "$context.identity.apiKey",
    "authorizer-principal-id" : "$context.authorizer.principalId",
    "caller" : "$context.identity.caller",
    "cognito-authentication-provider" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider",
    "cognito-authentication-type" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationType",
    "cognito-identity-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId",
    "cognito-identity-pool-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityPoolId",
    "http-method" : "$context.httpMethod",
    "stage" : "$context.stage",
    "source-ip" : "$context.identity.sourceIp",
    "user" : "$context.identity.user",
    "user-agent" : "$context.identity.userAgent",
    "user-arn" : "$context.identity.userArn",
    "request-id" : "$context.requestId",
    "resource-id" : "$context.resourceId",
    "resource-path" : "$context.resourcePath",
    "username" : "$context.authorizer.claims['cognito:username']"
    }
}
"event" : {
    "username" : "$context.authorizer.claims['cognito:username']"
}
```

Comment: Have you integrated API Gteway with cognito as mentioned in the doc?  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html

Answer (score 1):

You're sending the user's idToken with the call to API Gateway, right?

I assume that you are successfully getting the user's Cognito information in this solution.

In your call to API Gateway, you include an Authorization header with the token like so:

```
var url = YOURURL;
var options = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        'Authorization': COGNITOUSER_IDTOKEN
    }
}

fetch(url, options);
```

There are many ways to get your user's ID Token, so I will not prescribe that here.

As long as you're doing that, you can access the information in the token via the **Integration Request** (on of the stages of your API in API Gateway) mapping template.

In your mapping template, you can use this:

```
{
  "username" : "$context.authorizer.claims['cognito:username']"
}
```

Then, in your Lambda function, you can access this by referencing "event.username".

Comment: I'm not doing that. I will google on it. I just understand half of AWS documentation so I have a hard time finding what I am looking for. Please update the answer if you can instruct exactly how to attach the ID token. I will comment with a link to a resource with instructions if I get this to work.

Comment: I added the updated code showing how to send the ID Token.

Comment: If you want to troubleshoot your mapping template, you can do this: in your lambda function, console.log('Received event: ', event), and you'll be able to see what parameters are being passed through to your lambda. Your mapping template is passing through every possible parameter, which is fine, I suppose, but it definitely is not necessary.