# AWS Cognito + API Gateway, Authorize based on username

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have an API Gateway HTTP API. For some of the routes I've attached a Cognito User Pool authorizer which works fine. However now I want to add a restriction to the authorization so that only the user with the correct username can access a certain API.

For example, if the route is `PUT /users/{username}`, I only want the user with the corresponding username to be able to edit his/her profile information. For other users, it should be unauthorized.

This seems like a common use case, how do I do this? I've looked into scopes but that doesn't seem to be the solution. Would I have to write a custom Lambda authorizer for this, instead of using the Cognito authorizer? If so could you provide an example, since I have no experience writing the Lambda authorizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Mapping Template to structure a request in API Gateway, and use the information stored in a Cognito token from there https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference.

For your specific request to `/users/{username}`, you could use an if to only provide the desired information if the user matches [How to use IF condition in AWS Api gateway mapping templates. can i use if condition without using foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55546882/how-to-use-if-condition-in-aws-api-gateway-mapping-templates-can-i-use-if-condi).

Alternatively, you may be able to simplify the path to PUT to /users, then pull the username from the cognito token and use it in the mapping template [How can I access the Cognito username of the caller in a Lamda function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52648572/how-can-i-access-the-cognito-username-of-the-caller-in-a-lamda-function/52656269).